# Generation of 2D-ortho-mosaic image in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I am developing an Android application for image processing. In that, I first need to generate an ortho image by stitching 100+ images together. I have tried it in Android using Bitmap and Canvas. I first did it for 3 images. Is it the right way to generate an ortho or is there any better solution for this? Here is the code that I have used for stitching 3 images:

```
private void joinImages(File first, File second , File third) throws IOException
    {
        Bitmap bmp1, bmp2, bmp3;
        bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(first.getPath());
        bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(second.getPath());
        bmp3 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(third.getPath());

        int height = bmp1.getHeight()+bmp2.getHeight()+bmp3.getHeight();
        String height1 = height+"";
        Log.d(height1,"heght");

        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, bmp1.getHeight(), 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3,bmp1.getHeight()+bmp2.getHeight() , 0, null);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/final.jpg");
        bmOverlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        out.close();
}
```

As I am new to Android as well as image processing, I also want to know the difference between image stitching and 2D-orthomosaic generation. Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: This link might help you in combining multiple images into one http://whats-online.info/science-and-tutorials/92/how-to-combine-multiple-images-into-a-single-image-in-android/

Comment: So something like: https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/OpenDroneMap but on a phone? You might be better off doing the ortho image stitching on a server.

Comment: @FebiMathew When we're loading a combined image, we are getting an error: "W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (1080x4320, max=4096x4096)." Also, this combined image is made of only 3 individual images. Is there a way we can use Bitmap and Canvas for 100+ images  without exceeding this size limit? Or is there a way to load images that are greater than 4096x4096?